# Funcion "repr" no funciona correctamente

Tags: python

Estoy creando archivos para guardar objetos de Python, y me encuentro con que repr no funciona correctamente en algunos objetos, como las clases.

```
>>> repr(str) # lo que devuelve
"<class 'str'>"
>>> repr(str) # lo que deberia devolver
'str'
```

Answer (score 3):

`repr` funciona correctamente, eso es lo que debería imprimir.

Si quieres obtener el nombre de la clase como un string puedes hacer uso del atributo [`__name__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__name__).

```
>>> str.__name__
'str'

>>> int.__name__
'int'

>>> float.__name__
'float'
```

[`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) es utilizado principalmente para debugging, para mostrar información útil al programador. Si mostrara `"str"` como lo esperas, no habría mucha información útil que interpretar, simplemente sabrías que es un string que continene las letras *str*. En cambio si imprime `"<class 'str'>"`, ah, eso ya nos dice más cosas (aunque no es mucho).

Answer (score 0):

Para que `repr()` devuelva '`str`' debes pasarle el `string` "`str`", en cambio le estas pasando `str` que es una clase de `python` en efecto.